# Qt 5 Mac toolbar woes

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qt5, look-and-feel

I am trying to make a very simple toolbar in a QMainWindow on a Mac, with Qt 5.2.1, with not a single satisfaction. I was using still Qt 4.8 but I thought I'd give Qt5 a try.

As QtMacExtras are concerned, I don't find the native toolbar class anymore, except in private headers. So I tried a simple QToolbar.

I have a very basic and stupid toolbar:

```
setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(true);

toolbar_ = new QToolBar(this);

toolbar_->setMovable(false);
toolbar_->setFloatable(false);
toolbar_->addAction("h");
toolbar_->addAction("w");
toolbar_->addSeparator();
toolbar_->addAction("f");
```

As you can see, well, it isn't acceptable.

Is there any chance, by some arcane and weird means, that I could have a nice unified, or better "native look and feel", toolbar on a mac?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It seems that you're not adding the toolbar to a layout, right?

Comment: Well, I never added the toolbar to a layout in a main window... and it always worked on Qt 4.x (and before). Do you think this is the problem?

Comment: You never said it was a QMainWindow :) Sure, it should work on a main window.

Comment: Sorry!:) Yes, it is in a `QMainWindow`, so I think I should ditch Qt5, don't I?

Comment: I don't think you should ditch anything, you can file a bug, and you can try and debug it :)

Answer (score 1):

`QMainWindow::addToolBar(QToolBar *toolbar)` should do it.

The NSToolbar does not form part of the Qt widget hierarchy, so your admirably idiomatic conference of parenthood from the main window to the toolbar is working perfectly to specification, yet is obviously dissatisfying.

However, as the Trolls say in the QMainWindow documentation:

> "You add a toolbar to a main window with addToolBar()."

Here is the effect as shown in [rsync client for Mac](http://bonhardcomputing.com/truck/).
[image: Truck.app - the rsync client for mac - uses addToolBar]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my mac with me otherwise I would give this a quick test. I was surprised when browsing how many bugs are still being reported for Mac. I did find [this](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/04/08/mac-toolbars-for-qt-quick/) article, which does appear to have better looking toolbar.

Comment: Yeah, 2011 is pretty old. What changes would give it a better "look and feel?" IYO

Comment: For instance, spanning the whole window length would be the first and foremost issue. Since it shows as "cut" on the Mac, I'm starting to think Qt5 isn't ready and I'll switch back to Qt4, but alternatives to Qt are hard to find.